# How to specify line endings (CRLF)

Tags: newline, swagger-codegen, lf

We're using [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) 2.4.5 to generate models from our API. Everything is working exactly as we need with one relatively minor exception.

We're generating C# models, and as per windows these are typically stored with `CRLF` line endings. Whenever we run the generator these files are generated with the `LF` line endings.

We'd like all the models to be generated with `CRLF` instead of `LF`. Is there a way to modify this behaviour?

I've looked into how mustache is used - *a bit* - and read through the general [command line options](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#to-generate-a-sample-client-library) for codegen and the csharp specific options (`java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.4.5.jar config-help -l csharp`), and couldn't find anything.

**For further clarification:**

Currently this is a problem as each time you checkout then run generation again, then models appear as changed. This is simply because they're now *encoded* with `LF` line-endings, whereas git has checked them out as `CRLF` (which we cannot change)

The only other option I can think of at the moment, is to rewrite each file in the project with CRLF after the generation process has completed. I'd prefer it if there was a way via the generator tho.

Comment: Do you run codegen on Windows or Mac/*nix?

Comment: We run codegen on a windows PC

Comment: You'll probably need to open an issue at https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Comment: For now we have added a .gitattributes file to state that LF eol characters are expected and appropriate for this area of the repository. Not ideal but solves the immediate problem

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem and i'm not able to make my .gitattributes  file work. Can you post how your .gitattributes file looks like?

Comment: I can't remember exactly what the file looked like, but would have been along the lines of `*.cs  text eol=lf`. See this page for more examples https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Answer (score -1):

this is because of the config by Git. I think this blog will help you.
 [Configuring Git to handle line endings - GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)

solution

```sh
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Comment: My git config is already set to `autocrlf`, this affects the way line endings are committed. But doesn't affect the defection of changes locally. If a file is changed to have LF line endings from CRLF (as is happening here) git detects a change, even though the content hasn't (really) changed.